# colorbar with plotly in r

Tags: marker, plotly, colorbar

I got some trouble to set up the color of the colorbar in plotly
Here is the part of my script :

```
else if(is.na(pmatch("NGVS",limits[,ii]))&(max_value==min_value)){
  if (max_value==0){
    m<-list(
      colorbar = list(title = ii),
      size = 20, symbol = 'square',cmin=0,cmax=limits[,ii])

    mypalette=rev(rainbow(100,
                          start=rgb2hsv(col2rgb('blue'))[1], end=rgb2hsv(col2rgb('yellow'))[1]))

    p = plot_ly(graph3,x=Sampling.Date,y=Yaxis.,type="scatter",
                color=param_to_plot,colors= mypalette,mode="markers",marker = m)
    p = layout(p,yaxis = a,  xaxis=b, autosize = F, width = 700, height = 700, margin = q)
    print(p)
    rm(p)
```

What I want is to set up the colors of the colorbar to green to yellow. And as the points are all zeros they should all be green. For now, I only got a red colorscale from grey to red with all the points grey. And I don't know how to fix it up.                                                                           Thanks for your help